# Replacing rowNumber in a TableRow (React/Material-UI)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to replace the `rowNumber` within a `TableRow` in a `Table` in `material-ui`. In particular, I want to be able to grab a number using `onRowSelection` that is NOT the default row number. I've tried to replace the `rowNumber` by changing the `prop` within the `TableRow` like:

```
<TableRow rowNumber={row.id}>
```

However, this came up unsuccessful. Does anyone know of passing prop data on an `onClick` event (or `onRowSelection/cellClick`) effectively in `material-ui`?

I'm currently not using Redux, thus the possible solutions are not available to me. If moving the Redux is the best solution, then I will do so, but I want to see if I can handle this `onClick` event without relying on Redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux has nothing to do with this. Try attaching an `onClick` handler:

```
myCallback(rowId) {
  console.log(rowId);
}

render() {
  return (
    ...
    <TableRow rowNumber={row.id} onClick={() => { this.myCallback(row.id); }}>
  );
}
```